# Can not send Send keys values to specific CELLS

Tags: excel, vba, sendkeys

I am converting Eng names to Gujarati (Indian) language using IME Keyboard.
while executing script DO WHILE.. the script converts English names to gujarati using 'SendKeys' successfully,

```
Sub engtoguj_ref()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Dim currange As Range
    Dim strlen As Integer
    Dim newstr As String
    Dim countr As Integer
    Dim engstr As String
    Dim gujloc As String
    countr = 0
    engstr = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Value
    Do While (Len(engstr) > 0 And countr < 30)
       engstr = Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Value).Value
       MsgBox (engstr)
       countr = countr + 1
       newstr = " " & engstr & " "
       SendKeys newstr, True
       DoEvents
       ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
       MsgBox (ActiveCell.Address)
    Loop
    Application.MoveAfterReturn = True
End Sub
```

the Eng name is in column B, the gujarati name should be in column C.., instead it copies all the name together in Column C in the row next to last English Name.

Comment: Is always best to show a screenshot of how your data looks, and how you want it to look.

Comment: Sir, the English names are in column B and it should be converted to Gujarati in Column E. I am using Google Gujarati Input to convert English to Gujarati